# Can't load NetNamedPipeBinding

Tags: .net-core

I'm using a third party's dll to try to communicate with their program.  When I call a method to open a connection I get the error message

> "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Right now I'm doing this in a console app to just make sure I'm doing it right.  I can see in Microsoft's documentation that `NetNamedPipeBinding` is supposed to be a class in `System.ServiceModel` but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  I've downloaded all of the ServiceModel packages from NuGet but don't see any `NetNamedPipeBinding`.

I'm definitely a noob when it comes to a lot of this so please bear with any misuse of terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find it because you're using a .NET Core console application. If you take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding?view=netframework-4.8), you'll see:

> ### Applies to
>
> .NET Framework
> 4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0

Create a .NET Framework console application, and you'll be able to use it from `System.ServiceModel`.

Comment: and apparently the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) doesn't help with this :/ I just tried building a class library in .NET Core 3.1 that loads a component using this package and it throws at runtime